# What are the In App Purchase subscription durations when testing subscriptions through TestFlight?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight

When I test an internal development build In App purchase subscription durations are greatly reduced according to the table at:

http://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev7e89e149d

```
Actual Duration Test Duration
1 week          3 minutes
1 month         5 minutes
2 months        10 minutes
3 months        15 minutes
6 months        30 minutes
1 year          1 hour
```

In an internal development build when I purchase a 1 month subscription, it actually expires after 5 minutes.

**When I submit a build to iTunes Connect to use with Testflight, will my beta testers see the shortened durations (5 minutes) or will they see the actual durations (1 month)?**

Comment: I believe it's the same length of time because you're using the same sandbox.  It's easy to test, though, just add your app to TestFlight and only send it to yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The durations are the same as with other sandbox users.  Thanks @fsb

Answer (score 2):

The period provided in

[apple sandbox duration timings doc](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d)

are for reference purpose only and are approximate as told in this WWDC 2018 video
[engineering subscription](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/)
.They may or may not be of exact duration as given in the table. So one month in the sandbox may not be always equal to 5 minutes but in and around that.